# How to render a JSX that is inside a variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am doing an if/else statement to set the contents of the JSX element called 'signupMessage'. I later render the contents of 'signupMessage'.

```
render() {
  let signupMessage;
  if (this.state.signUpForNewsletter === true) {
    signupMessage = <h1>Thank you</h1>;
  } else if (this.state.signUpForNewsletter === false) {
    signupMessage = <h1>Be the first</h1> + <h1>to see the latest!</h1>;
  }
  return(
  <section className="sign-up">
    {signupMessage}
  </section>
)}
```

In the 'else if' block, I need two h1 tags in order to have control over exactly which words appear on a line, even on different devices, as per specs.

Right now, this outputs as "[object Object][object Object]". How do I get the JSX to render as h1 tags??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, this line:

```
<h1>Be the first</h1> + <h1>to see the latest!</h1>
```

gets transpiled to:

```
React.createElement("h1", null, "Be the first") +
React.createElement("h1", null, "to see the latest!");
```

`React.createElement` returns an object, and `object + object` in JS results in:

```
"[object Object][object Object]"
```

which is why you are seeing that output.

---

### How to fix this

Wrap the two `<h1>`s in a `<div>`:

```
signupMessage = <div><h1>Be the first</h1><h1>to see the latest!</h1></div>;
```

Comment: Kind of what I wrote, 5 minutes after my answer, but you got my vote for the `React.createElement` part :)

Comment: @Dekel, I upvoted your answer as well :). I felt that giving the extra explanation would add enough to the discussion to warrant another answer, hence this. (And thanks for the upvote.)

Comment: To me it seems way React handle JSX in variables differently, if one to place those html inside <section> tag it would work fine as I think.

Answer (score 3):

JSX elements must have a container:

```
render() {
  let signupMessage;
  if (this.state.signUpForNewsletter === true) {
    signupMessage = <h1>Thank you</h1>;
  } else if (this.state.signUpForNewsletter === false) {
    signupMessage = <div><h1>Be the first</h1><h1>to see the latest!</h1></div>;
  }
  return(
  <section className="sign-up">
    {signupMessage}
  </section>
)}
```

Instead of trying to concatenate the "string" (like you would have if it was html) - wrap them inside a new container and render that container.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a break where you need the second bit of the message to be on another line, and returning only a single h1 tag:

```
render() {
  let signupMessage;
  if (this.state.signUpForNewsletter === true) {
    signupMessage = <h1>Thank you</h1>;
  } else if (this.state.signUpForNewsletter === false) {
    signupMessage = <h1>Be the first<br />to see the latest!</h1>;
  }
  return(
  <section className="sign-up">
    {signupMessage}
  </section>
)}
```